# How to load remaining more results with scoll down to the end of the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dealing with a scroll down event to **display more results** when the **scroll bar goes down** to the end of the  tag.
I have a **division(div)** to which I am able to append 



 tags when the scroll bar goes down to the end. For that I have written the following code.

#### In the script:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {        
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('#main').height() - 200 ) {
        fun();
    }
  });
  var fun= function(){    
    $('p').appendTo("#main");
    setTimeout(fun2, 100);      
  }
  var fun2=function(){
   $("#main").append("<p>Hello Scroll me</p>");  
  }
 });

</script>
```

#### In the body:

```
<div id="main">
  <p  style='height:100px;'>Hello Scroll me</p><p  style='height:100px;'>Hello Scroll   me</p><p  style='height:100px;'>Hello Scroll me</p><p  style='height:100px;'>Hello Scroll me</p><p  style='height:100px;'>Hello Scroll me</p><p  style='height:100px;'>Hello Scroll me</p><p  style='height:100px;'>Hello Scroll me</p><p  style='height:100px;'>Hello Scroll me</p><p  style='height:100px;'>Hello Scroll me</p>

</div>
```

I have achieved this, but what exactly I need is:

I have 100 'p' tags in a division(), I want to display **10 p's** at first and when I move the scroll bar down to the end I want to display **next 10(Total 20)**...so on.
For that I am not getting what to do.

Can anybody please help me **with out** referring any scoll plug inns

Comment: I can not do with any plug ins please.

Comment: Apologies, I overlooked the last line. I will delete that comment.

Comment: @Thrustmaster : No problem, I didnt' mind.

Comment: @VenkatK Are those 100 `p` tags already loaded, but just hidden from view?

Comment: Those are already loaded. I want them to be hidden until the scroll bar reaches down.

Comment: How are they hidden? With a class?

Comment: Probably with a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
  <!-- <p> tags here -->
</div>
<span id="indicator"></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#main p").addClass("hidden");
  while ($("#main").outerHeight() < window.innerHeight) {
    showNextTen();
  }

  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    if (($("span").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) <= window.innerHeight) {
      showNextTen();
    }
  });
});

function showNextTen() {
  $("#main p.hidden").slice(0, 10).removeClass("hidden");
}
```

The `span` outside the `#main` div is used as indicator to check whether the scrollbar has reached the bottom of the page.

And by the way, I just used a `while` loop to load not just the first 10 `p`s, because if only the first 10 are loaded there's a chance that their not long enough to produce the scrollbar, so scroll event can be triggered and it will all be useless. But if you want the first 10 only you can just remove the `while` loop and instead call `showNextTen()` immediately.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your markup is, but if you are using a class you can remove the class from the first 10 instances of the class, and then the next ten instances and so on.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {        
   if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('#main').height() - 200 ) {
       $('.hidden:lt(9)').removeClass('hidden');
   }
});
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YcwPe/)